# How do I change XML entity declaration programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to change the XML entity declaration programmatically in below xml.
I want to read it and change the ENTITY string "Custom/spaus.xml" to some other string or location.

```
<!DOCTYPE MYFILE SYSTEM "../../../Data/dtd/Language.dtd"[
 <!ENTITY CustomMyDoc SYSTEM "Custom/MyDoc.xml">]>
<MYFILE>
   <File VALUE="SPAUS" DESC="This File is in custom" MEDIA="DEFAULT">
        <DETAIL VALUE="DISPLAY">Español</DETAIL>
        &CustomMyDoc;
        <KEY VALUE="ACCT_CH">Cuenta de Cheques</KEY>
        <KEY VALUE="ACCT_SV">Ahorros</KEY>
        <KEY VALUE="ACCT_OT">Otros</KEY>
     </FILE>
  </MYFILE>
```

I tried reading the xml using XmlTextReader and load the xml in XmlDocument and then fetch the XmlEntity but then I am unable to change the desired value.

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
     try
     {
        using (XmlTextReader myXmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath))
        {
           xmlDoc.Load(myXmlTextReader);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Exception ex = new Exception(String.Format("Error parsing XML file '{0}': {1}", xmlPath, e.Message), e);
        Logger.LogException(ex);
        return;
     }

     XmlNamedNodeMap nMap = xmlDoc.DocumentType.Entities;

     if (nMap.Count > 0)
     {
        XmlEntity node = (XmlEntity)nMap.Item(0);            
     }
```

Now I am clueless how to move forward the "Custom\Spaus.xml" comes in XmlEntity.SystemId; property but that is read only.